# Commit button won't work when adding a record to Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So I've been doing this personal project for myself where I'm trying to create a program where the user (me in this case) can add, delete, update a database via a form where I can fill out the necessary information.

To give a general idea, the main form has a data grid view where if I click load, the database appears wit the records. I got all of that set. However where I am having trouble is in Form1 which is the adding a record form where I write down the information and after filling it out I press the "commit" button so that it can write it on the MS Access Database. This is a general view of the code I have inside commit button. Just for reference, Profiles is the name of the mdb file and Contacts is the name of the table containing the recods.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click
If inc <> 0 Then 
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da) 
        Dim dsnewrow As DataRow 

        dsnewrow = ds.Tables("Profiles").NewRow() 

        dsnewrow.Item("First_Name") = FirstNameText.Text 
        dsnewrow.Item("Last_Name") = LastNameText.Text

        ds.Tables("Profiles").Rows.Add(dsnewrow) 
        da.Update(ds, "Profiles")

        Main.DataGridView1.Refresh() 


        MsgBox("New Record added")

    End If
End Sub
```

What I don't know is if it's necessary to add this following code to Form1_load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "Data Source= path to the mdb file"


        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()
        Sql = "SELECT * FROM Contacts"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Profiles")

        con.Close()
        Maxrows = ds.Tables("Profiles").Rows.Count
        inc = -1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

the following are declared, just for reference:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet 
Dim dbProvider, dbSource As String
Dim sql As String
Dim Maxrows As Integer
```

Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement on this line:`da.Update(ds, "Profiles")`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been at it for days unfortunately :/

Let me know if you need any additional information to clarify.

Comment: are there more columns in the database than just First, Last names?

Comment: Yeah, there are. There's the address1, address2, zipcode, phone, email, notes

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your `btnCommit_Click` method after

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
```

add the following:

```
cb.QuotePrefix = "["
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

Does that help?

Comment: well, it certainly got rid of the error message but nothing happens :/